# Rails: best practice to count key values in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a User model that has a meta column with a hash, for example {"version"=>"1.0", "country"=>"UK"}

What is the best practice / efficient way to count each individual values in any key? So I might want to figure out how many records have country = UK or USA or France, etc. I do not know all the possible values in each key beforehand...

I guess I can do it in a big loop

```
User.all.each do |user|
  user.meta["country"] ..........
```

but is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You can let the database do the work if you didn't serialize the fields into a meta column. I don't see how to avoid looping through all the records otherwise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there's `group_by`

```
arr = [{"version" => "1.0", "country" => "UK"},
       {"version" => "1.0", "country" => "France"},
       {"version" => "1.0", "country" => "UK"},
       {"version" => "1.0", "country" => "USA"},
       {"version" => "1.0", "country" => "France"},
       {"version" => "1.0", "country" => "UK"}]
grouped = arr.group_by {|el| el["country"]}
#=> {"UK"=>[{"version"=>"1.0", "country"=>"UK"}, 
#           {"version"=>"1.0", "country"=>"UK"}, 
#           {"version"=>"1.0", "country"=>"UK"}], 
#    "France"=>[{"version"=>"1.0", "country"=>"France"}, 
#               {"version"=>"1.0", "country"=>"France"}], 
#    "USA"=>[{"version"=>"1.0", "country"=>"USA"}]}
grouped.map {|k,v| [k, v.length]}
# => [["UK", 3], ["France", 2], ["USA", 1]]
```

Comment: this looks promising, but how to I get to the structure of your "arr" from my model?

I tried `User.all.group_by{|meta| meta["country"]}.map do {|k,v| [k, v.length]}` but doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: Try `User.all.group_by {|user| user.meta["country"]}...`. Remember, `User.all` returns an "Array" of `User`s, not of `meta` columns.

Comment: you are right!!! This is fantastic!!! thank you so much :)
one minor note: i got this to work without the `do` in the map step

Comment: You're right; slip in transcription from my irb session. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have serialized value in sql DB it's only way to work with this values to iterate them. But several NOSQL BDs allow to iteract with such values using BD's tools (like mongo)

Answer (score 0):

You can do so to count all users who have meta['country'] == 'UK'

```
User.all.inject{|count, u| count += 1 if u.meta['country'] == 'UK'}
```

Comment: this will be handy in the future. Thanks much!